# JavaScript - this keyword inside an object method

Tags: javascript, object, methods, this

I'm expecting to see the value of 26 returned to the console based on the following code snippet, but I get 'undefined'. Have I used the 'this' keyword incorrectly?

```
const myDetails = {
  name: "peter",
  birthYear: 1996,
  calcAge: function () {
    this.age = 2022 - this.birthYear;
    return this.age;
  },
  gender: "male"
}

console.log(myDetails.age);
```

Comment: There's only an `age` in the function that is stored in the `calcAge` property of the `myDetails` object. `myDetails.name` or `myDetails.birthYear` or `myDetails.calcAge()` would work - but not `myDetails.age`

Comment: but by returning this.age, doesn't that mean it's available to reference outside of the method?

Comment: You're not calling `.calcAge()` so there's nothing returned. Also `return this.age` would return the content of `this.age` and not some magic variable with the same name of the property/variable the function returns.

Comment: You never declare age value you can call (myDetails.calcAge())

Comment: the goal was to print the value of the age key to the console. This solution invokes the object method, but doesn't print the value of age to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change your code a little bit. it should be work now. when you call the function you must need to use function name.

```
const myDetails = {
    name: "peter",
    birthYear: 1996,
    calcAge: function() {
        this.age = 2022 - this.birthYear;
        return this.age;
    },
    gender: "male"
}
console.log(myDetails.calcAge());//Here
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I've figured it out now...

The object method hasn't been invoked yet! Because function expressions are treated in order (which this object method is... a function expression!) whereas function DECLARATIONS can be added anywhere in the file, but will be automatically "hoisted" to the top.

So in this case, the function needs to be invoked first.

So this works for me, and creates a new key pair of **age: 26**

```
const myDetails = {
  name: "peter",
  birthYear: 1996,
  calcAge: function () {
    this.age = 2022 - this.birthYear;
    return this.age;
  },
  gender: "male"
}
// invoke the object method
myDetails.calcAge();
console.log(myDetails.age);
```

Comment: Doesn't really matter whether the function was created using a declaration or expression, neither of those would automatically call it.

Comment: my understanding was that you cannot use a declaration as an object method

Comment: Not inside the object literal, yes, but you could declare it before and then use it as a property, making it a method just as if you had used a function expression. But either way: neither would invoke the function.